# wxWidgets controls paint/draw/display issue on Windows

Tags: wxwidgets

I built a small wxFrame GUI, originally on Linux using CodeLite+wxCrafter, but on Windows the controls are not visible until I click on a notebook page and back, or resize the form, or hover the mouse over a control. I created a new Windows CodeLite+wxCrafter project and it does not display this issue. I tried comparing all the details between the two projects to see what differences there were, but couldn't find any that fixed the issue. I'm puzzled.

For example, this is what I see when I run the app:

[image]

After clicking on the Advanced Page and then back to the Run Page or resizing the form, this is what I see:

[image]

Or if I hover my mouse over say a wxButton (Open) it shows up:

[image]

This is what it should look like, after I click on the Advanced Page and back to the Run Page or resize the form, and then hover my mouse across all the text controls.

[image]

Any ideas what the display issue is?

Comment: This is very difficult to answer without knowing anything about your code. Try reproducing the problem in the wxWidgets "notebook" sample, if you can make it happen there, it would hopefully be possible to have at least some idea about what's going on.

Comment: I tried the notebook sample, no issues that I could see. I "fixed" this issue by adding a new notebook page and moving all the controls over. But still having a display paint issue with the background color of a text control. The background color doesn't show until the mouse is moved out of the control.

Comment: Can you add your code or part of your code here. Even if you have fixed the problem, If there is no code in this question no one can answer it. If there is no answer here the question will not help any one who has the same problem.

Comment: I've made my repository public, would love some feedback. Thanks.

https://bitbucket.org/blounsbury/hydrosense_wx